# Change font color of a timer overtime

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a great example to help me explain what I'm trying to do!

"The countdown label changes each second, and the colour gradually shifts from green to red as the countdown proceeds."

How does this work? If someone could please explain in the simplest manner I'd really appreciate it!

I know it must use JavaScript and use innerHTML

I found a link that calls it Display Morphing and uses AJAX. The problem, is my instructor never told me we had to use AJAX. Is Display Morphing the proper term for what I am trying to do?

http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Display_Morphing.php

Am I headed in the right direction with this code? Do I put some type of function after the "innerHTML =" to tell the page how/when I want the font color to change?

```
var hoursElement = document.getElementById("hours");
        hoursElement.innerHTML = 
var minutesElement = document.getElementById("minutes");
        minutesElement.innerHTML = 
var secondsElement = document.getElementById("seconds");
        secondsElement.innerHTML =
```

Comment: Does your instructor want us to give you the whole answer?

Comment: @Smandoli Not sure. I do not want anyone to give me the whole answer, then I wont learn! :) I just want someone to tell me if I am going in the right direction. I will be happy to post my findings once I have my results.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need Ajax for this. You use `innerHTML` to set the text that is displayed. Use `hoursElement.style.color = ...` to set the colour of that text.

Comment: @nnnnnn by setting, is that making the timer stay at one color, or will in gradually change has the time runs out?

Comment: You would need to repeatedly set `.style.color` to a series of different colours, it doesn't happen automatically. Each time you change the displayed value calculate what the next colour should be and set it. I assume you already know to use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to control the actual timing of the thing?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'll research it right now. Thank you for pointing me in a new direction!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on your way to updating the time display.  Here's a couple additional hints to help you on your way:

1. Ajax is not needed and will only complicate things.  Look into `setTimeout` and `Date`, which should be enough for what you need.
2. For text color, once you have a dom element in a var (say `timeContainer`), you can change the color of internal text with `timeContainer.style.color = '#RRGGBB';` Where RR, GG, BB are the hex numbers of the amount of red, green, and blue in the text.
3. If you don't know about it yet, check out http://jsfiddle.net, which will help you quickly set up and test your html and JavaScript to see if it is working.